# Changing CSS properties via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I need a function to change the appearance of some elements in my HTML page "on the fly", but I am not able to do it.

The problem is that I cannot use a command like

```
document.write ('<style type="text/css">body {background-color: #cccccc;}</style>');
```

because I need to make the changes effective when the page is already loaded, using a link like

```
<a onmouseclick="Clicker(1)" href="#">clic</a>
```

and I cannot use a command like

```
document.body.style.background = '#cccccc';
```

because I do not know if it can be applied to other not so easy cases, because I need to change the appearance of elements such as `td.myclass` or sibling elements such as `th[scope=col]+th[scope=col]+th[scope=col]`.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I voted all of them because each one has taught something that I didn't know.
I accepted the one that for my problem is the simplest to follow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The stylesheets can be manipulated directly in JS with the [`document.styleSheets` list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets).

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Modifying a stylesheet rule with CSSOM</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1];
stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
</script>
<body>
The stylesheet declaration for the body's background color is modified via JavaScript.
</body>
</html>
```

The example is by Mozilla Contributors and copied from:

- [Using dynamic styling information - Web API Interfaces | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information)

Comment: This seems like it would be an incredible pain in the ass. You'd have to either examine the `cssText` property of each `CSSRule` object in each `cssRules` collection in each of the `CSSStyleSheet` objects or you'd have to rely on the relevant rule being in a specific order in the (nested) collections.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily access and modify CSS propery of any DOM by setting properties of the style object. i.e. to change the background color of a DOM element with id of #yourid you do this

```
document.getElementById('yourid').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
```

note that CSS properties that are made up of two names seperated by an hyphen, i.e background-color, font-size are turned into camelCase notation, i.e backgroundColor and fontSize while single worded properties retain their respective names

Comment: It'd be useful to modify CSS properties directly so that they apply to elements added dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[NUMBER].style['background-color'] = '#ccc';
```

Example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].style['background-color'] = '#ccc';
document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[1].style['background-color'] = '#ccc';
```

If you want change all td.myclass

```
var myObj = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
for(var i=0; i<myObj.length; i++){
  myObj[i].style['background-color'] = '#ccc';
}
```

Comment: That syntax isn’t right; the standard way is to use camelCase, e.g. `myObj[i].style.backgroundColor`. But a dot followed by a bracket isn’t valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `id` attribute for as many elements as you like, but they must be unique.
You can also use the `class` attribute, but to find the specific element you want will be bit tougher.

Then, using JavaScript, you can use the `document.getElementById` function to retrieve the DOMElement object to set CSS properties on. For classes, you will need to first get all the elements with the specified tag name by calling `document.getElementsByTagName`, then iterating over the resulting array and checking if each element has the provided class name, and if it does, then adding to an array, which after the loop gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, img, ol, ul,
    li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
     font-family:Segoe UI, sans-serif;
    }
   .header, .container, .footer {
    min-height:100px;
   }
   .header {
    background-color:#757575;
   }
   .container {
       background-color:#cccccc;
   }
   .footer {
    background-color:#757575;   
   }
   .header, .footer, .column {
    text-align:center;
   }
   .column {
    float:left;
    min-width:300px;
    border-left:1px solid blue;
    border-right:1px solid blue;
    margin-left:10px;
   }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function headerContentFooter(headerRatio, footerRatio) {
    totalHeight = document.height;
    headerHeight = 0;
    containerHeight = 0;
    footerHeight = 0;
    if(headerRatio < 0.5 && footerRatio < 0.5) {
     headerHeight = totalHeight * headerRatio;
     footerHeight = totalHeight * footerRatio;
     containerHeight = totalHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight);
     document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].style.height = "" + headerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.height = "" + containerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.height = "" + footerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].style.minHeight = "" + headerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.minHeight = "" + containerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.minHeight = "" + footerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].style.maxHeight = "" + headerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.maxHeight = "" + containerHeight + "px";
     document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.maxHeight = "" + footerHeight + "px";
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="column">LEFT</div><div class="column">CENTER</div><div class="column">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   headerContentFooter(0.05, 0.05);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use complex selector like `th[scope=col]`, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)