# Is there a way to expand row height in PXGrids?

Tags: acumatica

The customer will have users using a touch screen device to interact with the system. They will need to select a row from a grid with a hyperlinked field in it. I don't want them to accidentally click a row they didn't intend on clicking. Is there a way to expand each row so that there is more space between the links on each row?

EDIT: Only a few screens will be used by the users that are using the touch screen devices. The rest of the users will be using the system normally. I would only like the rows in which these users are interacting with made larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change padding properties of `GridRow` CSS class. The first and last padding values determine the top and bottom padding of the grid row element.

The change can be made in file `\App_Themes\Default\00_Controls.css`.
I changed top padding to 27 pixels and bottom padding to 25 pixels in this example:

```
.GridRow {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E4E8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--activerow-color, #E0E4E8);
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: White;
  padding: 27px 8px 25px;
  line-height: 16px;
  min-height: 17px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change just a specific grid's row's padding instead of all grids in Acumatica? I should have mentioned not all users will be using the touch screen, so I don't want all screens to appear like that.

Comment: CSS styles are global to the website. To apply per page you would need to use JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442989/7376238

How to include JavaScript in Acumatica:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006748/dynamically-change-button-color